# How to override smtp host details while using sendmail

Tags: linux, sendmail

I have a requirement to send the output of certain output as an email to myself.
like `df -h , free -m` etc.
I have used mailx command with override of smtp host with command `mailx -S smtp="smtphost.com"` , I was able to receive the mail but the formatting was not correct and it came as a `text/plain content type`. It is not aligned and it is getting difficult to read the content.

In all the forums/blogs, I saw that we will be able to send the html content inside mail using sendmail. But I wanted to try out by overriding the smtp host. But unable to do the same. Any help would be much appreciated.

I am thinking that there has to be a way in mailx command which allows the mail to be send with html format or atleast the tab spaced output as seen in the linux. if this doesn't work by anyways then I need to get the sendmail working.

Comment: Why don't you simply install postfix on the system and send email as `df -h | mail -s "subject" email@example.com`

Comment: Postfix is installed. I tried the same command already , used mail , mailx. but I am not getting a formatted email. It is still coming as text/plain.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `-a` switch with `mailx`. You can add the formatted file as an attachment:

```
echo '<html><b>This is and HTML message</b></html>' > /tmp/abc.htm
echo "test from $USERNAME attached" | mailx -s "Test message" -a /tmp/abc.htm user@your.dom
```

If you want formatted output (`ls -l` for example) pipe the output to `abc.txt` and attach the same way.

Comment: I tried this already. but in outlook it is still coming as text/plain

Comment: I guess I've used Thunderbird forever so viewing attachments 'in-line' gets me close enough. I think what you're looking for is a way to actually modify the mime-type of the message body. Likely you need an MUA which supports modifying the message headers; `mutt` supposedly does this as well as *some* versions of `mailx`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805783/send-html-page-as-email-using-mutt

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK [sendmail by sendmail.org](http://www.sendmail.org) does not support specifying smtp relay via command line by an ordinary user.

**BUT** You may use "sendmail look alike" e.g. [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/)

Many unix/linux programs provide "sendmail look alike" - executable program supporting basic/typical sendmail command line options used when sending email.  Other MTA/SMTP servers install such look as `sendmail`.